Need ideas for insulating a Sun Room to make it a full season room
I have a sun room (20'x14') with non-insulated windows on 3 sides and brick wall on house side with sliding door. It has a peaked ceiling with wood rafters under roofing materials. The floor is on concrete and carpeted. It is cold in the winter and extremely hot in the summer. I just purchased a heating/cooling unit, but it cannot cool the room in the summer. I would like ideas for how to insulate the room to make it a year around room in Michigan.

Pictures would help. How much of the 3 non-brick walls are windows? Is the sliding door double-pane?

You could start by replacing the windows with insulated windows.  What is the wall construction of the 3 not-brick walls?  Entirely window?  Partially solid wall?

How many hours of sun per day does this room get?

Thank you for your response. All 3 sides have windows with 2.5 feet of brick between floor and windows. Windows are single pane (considering tinting, not replacing). The room was build on outside of house with a sliding single pane double door between house and room. Gets sun entire day. Ceiling is open rafters, peaked with air vent across top of peak. Just installed a heating/cooling unit, but it cannot compete with the heat. Expect it will be sufficient in the winter because the room was rapidly heated before with a small gas stove (removed). The problem is the summer heat.
